# Dynamic queries in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my project I'm using Hibernate and write now I'm struggling with one issue. In the project which I'm working on, I need to create something like dynamic queries. Let me present what is going on...

I have 8 different queries. The `SELECT`, `FROM` and first `WHERE` clause is the same for each query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., colX FROM table WHERE col1 = :param1;
```

The point is that based on one parameter the rest of the query is different in each case. Cases below:

1. Simple query - just the base for the other queries.
2. One more `WHERE` condition: `AND col2 = :param2`.
3. The same like in previous one, but condition on different column: `AND col3 = :param2`.
4. More complex - `JOIN` clause, in the `WHERE` clause second condition again on different column, but also here we have `UNION` with exactly the same query like in point 3.
5. The same like query no. 4, but with different column in `WHERE` clause before `UNION` statement.
6. Same rule as in query 5.
7. Same rule as in query 5.
8. Here only `JOIN` and in `WHERE` clause are 3 conditions instead of 2.

I thought that's it, but I just remind that for all of these queries, we could apply dynamically extra `WHERE` conditions, but they need to appear in both `SELECT`s if there is a `JOIN`.

Does it even possible? Right now I solve the problem by passing correct columns names to the method with the `StringBuilder` and the `if ... else` statements, which takes care of `UNION`, `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions.

I'm not proud of it, I don't like it, but I don't know how to resolve this problem better...

Comment: What's the extra parameter, on which the rest of the `WHERE` clauses depend? How do you handle it's value and  can you show a code sample of what you did exactly, I think it will be more interesting to see it in the code.

Comment: One solution that I have in mind is to create a view, which will return different parts of it, based on the external parameter: `create or replace view view_over_table
As
select 'external_param_value1' as ext_value, col1, col2 from table where condition1
union
select 'external_param_value2' as ext_value, col1, col2 from table where condition1 and condition2;`. Then you would do: `SELECT * FROM view_over_table where ext_value = :external_param_that_determines_the_logic;` - Would that do ? By doing this you could hide the complexity behind the view ... which seems ok to me.

Comment: It's just some value and depends on it, the correct query (one of these eight) should be created. The view is not correct, because I think that you didn't noticed that some queries could have `JOIN` or `UNION` or even both at the  same time.

Comment: It's not a problem to create a view, which has different queries in it, combined by unions let's say, as long as they have the same columns / datatypes in their select statements. So the benefit of the view is that you hide the complexity behind it and you can easily get the proper query out of it, by a single parameter. The sample view I provided is indeed ... a sample one, but on top of it you can even have another view, which you select only '' as ext_value, col1 and col2 out of. See that's why I asked about the parameter that decides what is getting selected and the 8 queries also .

Comment: It's just a Java parameter. It's the parameter related with some kind of level. And depending on that level we decide how to create a query (if we need to use `JOIN` and `UNION`) and which columns should be in the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think Criteria API of Hibernate should help you with this. 
Some examples:
http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries